# Surveillance or monitoring

Tags: differences

What better way to express " I'm watching you (spy)" :

Surveillance or monitoring (monitor)?

What's the difference?

Comment: Optimal word choice depends on context....

Answer (score 1):

> Observe

It doesn't have a negative meaning in the right context, e.g. a manager observing employees' performance.

E.g. We are observing your performance.

E.g. How to observe and give feedback to employees.

[Source](http://blink.ucsd.edu/HR/supervising/appraisal/observation.html)

Answer (score 0):

**"We have you under surveillance"** would be crystal clear but rather creepy. Why would you want to tell people "I'm watching you" if you are monitoring them for suspicious behavior? Wouldn't that defeat the purpose of "spying" on them?